# Showing iFrame only after its source content has been completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a iFrame on my page thats display style is none. I have a javascript function to set the source and then set the display to block. The problem is that the iframe shows up before the content of it is loaded and thus I get a flickering effect. It goes white first and then displays the content. So I need to set the source, and when done loading all content of its source, only set its display style.

CSS & Javascript

```
.ShowMe{display:block;}

function(url)
{
document.getElementById('myIFrame').src = url;
document.getElementById('myIFrame').className = ShowMe;
}
```

Comment: are you using .load or ajax() to load the content ??

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: The javascript function that sets the src gets called from a anchor.. ("Show Form" Label) so it does not get done on the load of the page and yet the iFrame is on the same domain. This is intranet project.

Comment: Normally the iframe is hidden at first, and the inner page's load event tells the parent page to show itself(assuming there no cross domain issue, which otherwise would be a bit more complicated). But this only guarantees the inner page itself is loaded, not necessarily everything (images, css, js etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you try the following:

```
<script type="javascript">
    var iframe = document.createElement("myIFrame");
    iframe.src = url;

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1 && !window.opera){
                iframe.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (iframe.readyState == "complete"){            
                //not sure if your code works but it is below for reference
                  document.getElementById('myIFrame').class = ShowMe;
                  //or this which will work
                  //document.getElementById("myIFrame").className = "ShowMe";

                }
            };
        }       
        else 
        {
            iframe.onload = function(){
                  //not sure if your code works but it is below for reference
                  document.getElementById('myIFrame').class = ShowMe;
                  //or this which will work
                  //document.getElementById("myIFrame").className = "ShowMe";
            };
        } 
</script>
```

Based on the code found [here](http://wordpressapi.com/2010/01/28/check-iframes-loaded-completely-browser/).

Comment: That is his code that he was using, I assumed it worked for him

Comment: @Teemu I've updated the answer with some of my own code for proper handling of the class setting in addition to his own so he knows where it's supposed to be :)

Comment: What he meant is .className, This is how you set the css class for element via javascript. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's simple as that:

```
<iframe onload="this.style.opacity=1;" style="opacity:0;border:none;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this within the `iframe`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.frameElement.className = 'ShowMe'; // 'ShowMe' or what ever you have in ShowMe variable.
}
```

Since you've tagged your question with `[jquery]`, I assume you have executed the code within [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). It is fired when the DOM is ready, i.e. it uses native [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event (if available).  [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/load) is fired, when all resources on the page are ready.